# How to apply a SWIG typemap for a double pointer struct argument

Tags: python, c, pointers, swig

I have an API that I am trying to wrap using SWIG such that I can call the underlying C library from python.

I have got stuck with a particular API fn:

```
int update_tracks(track_t **phash_tracks,
                  const pdws_t *pdw_frame,
                  const rdws_t *rdw_frame,
                  lib_t *lib,
                  lib_meta_t *lib_meta,
                  const cfg_t *cfg);
```

Its the double pointer to `track_t` data structure that I can't handle.

All the single pointers work fine.

This is the only API fn that has a double pointer to `track_t`

All the others only have a single pointer, e.g.

```
void print_hash_tracks(const track_t *hash_tracks, const cfg_t *cfg,
                       enum TRKTYPE trktype);
```

I'm pretty sure I need to make a typemap in my SWIG interface file (interface.i) but I am finding the SWIG docs impenetrable.

What I think I need to do is create a typemap that whenever it sees the `track_t**` type, it takes a `track_t*` and converts it to its address, something like:

```
/* provide typemap to handle instances of track_t** parameters */
%typemap(in) track_t** (track_t *tracks) {
    $1 = &tracks;
}
```

but I'm just getting segmentation faults when I run:

```
tracks = g3.track_t()
g3.update_tracks(tracks, pdw_frame, rdw_frame, lib, lib_meta, cfg)
```

on the python side.

I feel like I've almost solved this but can't quite get the typemap specification right and at the same time struggling to understand the relevant documentation.

flexo - if you're out there - maybe you can shed some light on this, you seem to be the SO expert in this area..

UPDATE - m7ython (brilliant! another SWIG expert on SO)

Usage in C is pretty straigthforward

declare and initialise a track_t pointer to NULL:

```
track_t *hash_tracks = NULL;
```

then:

```
update_tracks(&hash_tracks, &pdw_frame, &rdw_frame,
              &lib, &lib_meta, &cfg);
```

So the address of the pointer to `track_t` is passed as an arg to `update_tracks()`. The `update_tracks()` fn takes care of all the necessary mallocs for the data that gets put into `hash_tracks`, i.e. the hash table of `track_t` structs

All the other args are single pointers and I can create and populate them with no issues on the python side.

`track_t` is a struct containing a bunch of ints, floats, char* etc. e.g.

```
typedef struct
{
/* make struct hashable */
UT_hash_handle hh;

int id;
...
char name[MAX_BUF];
...
} track_t;
```

The reason that the track_t arg is a `track_t**` and not just a `track_t*` is because `hash_tracks` is a pointer to a hash table (using the UTHash library). `hash_tracks` points to the 1st track_t in the hash table. In the body of the `update_tracks()` fn track_t structs can be added/removed from the hash table, such that the pointer to the 1st track_t may change, i.e. `hash_tracks` may point to something else after the call to `update_tracks()`, hence the reason for passing a pointer to the pointer.

In other words, the `track_t**` arg, `phash_tracks` is being used both as an input and output type arg, hence the pointer to a pointer. All the other args are simply inputs, they don't change so they can be passed in as single pointers.

I attempted the 'helper fn' route with the following C fn:

```
track_t** make_phash_tracks(void)
{
    track_t **phash_tracks;

    phash_tracks = calloc(1, sizeof(track_t*));

    return phash_tracks;
}
```

the use of calloc should ensure that *phash_tracks is NULL

this compiled and wrapped with no errors, but when I used it from the python side it segfaulted, e.g.

```
phash_tracks = g3.make_phash_tracks()
g3.update_tracks(phash_tracks, pdw_frame, rdw_frame, lib, lib_meta, cfg)
```

checking the `phash_tracks` var just prior to calling `update_tracks` gave:

```
(Pdb) p phash_tracks
<Swig Object of type 'track_t **' at 0x7fb9e37c9030>
```

Comment: I have no knowledge of SWIG, but looking at the function call, are you sure you are passing the double pointer correctly? It seems you are not passing the address of `tracks` but the value itself.

Comment: TBH if you have no knowledge of SWIG you're prob not going to be able to shed much light. The typemap is attempting to convert the tracks pointer to a double pointer. It gets incorporated into the auto generated wrapper code I believe

Comment: Can you give an example in C of how you would use `update_tracks`? Currently, your typemap passes a `track_t**` to an uninitialized `track_t *`, and does not use the `track_t**` after the function has completed. If you can get your hands on a `track_t**` using the C library, then SWIG should just wrap this, and you can simply pass it into the `update_tracks` function (without any typemaps). Perhaps you can write a helper function in C: `track_t** make_phash_tracks(track_t* tracks) { return &tracks; }`.

Comment: I've been trying to build the same interface but for java rather than python - should this be possible? I'm getting a lot of compile time errors, things like SWIG_ConvertPtr, SWIG_POINTER_OWN, SWIG_POINTER_DISOWN are undeclared

Comment: I also noted that the %append_output appears 'unsubstituted' in the output c wrapper code when java is the target - that can't be right..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: Ok, I think I now understand what `update_tracks`does. It seems you can use the function in two ways. Either to update existing `tracks`, or to create `tracks` if you pass a pointer to a `NULL` pointer. I am not sure about the most elegant way to handle both cases in SWIG (or if this is even a problem), but here are some options.

#### 1. `phash_tracks` is an output argument

First, you **must** pass `*phash_tracks` back to Python as a return value, and use the function in some form like

```
>>> int_res, tracks = g3.update_tracks(tracks, pdw_frame, rdw_frame, lib, lib_meta, cfg)
```

or

```
>>> int_res, tracks = g3.update_tracks(pdw_frame, rdw_frame, lib, lib_meta, cfg)
```

This is accomplished by the following "argout" typemap:

```
%typemap(argout) track_t **phash_tracks {
  %append_output(SWIG_NewPointerObj(%as_voidptr(*$1), $*1_descriptor, SWIG_POINTER_OWN));
}
```

Maybe you don't want Python to take ownership of the `track_t*`, then replace `SWIG_POINTER_OWN` by `0`.

#### 2. Passing an empty `phash_tracks`

If you only want to use the `update_tracks` function to *create* `tracks`, you can do essentially what you are already doing. Use the following "in" typemap, and use the function as in the second example above (without the `tracks` parameter).

```
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) track_t **phash_tracks (track_t *tracks) {
  tracks = NULL;
  $1 = &tracks;
}
```

#### 3. `phash_tracks` as an input (and output) argument

If you want to use `update_tracks` to update *existing* `tracks`, you should be able to use the "in" typemap I suggested before, and use the function from Python as in the first example (including the `tracks` parameter).

```
%typemap(in) track_t **phash_tracks (track_t *tracks) {
  if ((SWIG_ConvertPtr($input, (void **) &tracks, $*1_descriptor, SWIG_POINTER_EXCEPTION | SWIG_POINTER_DISOWN)) == -1)
    return NULL;
  $1 = &tracks;
}
```

Note that it is important that Python disowns its `tracks_t*`.

#### 4. Enabling both (2) and (3) above

You could basically use version (3) also to *create* `tracks`, if you could get swig to pass a wrapped `NULL` `tracks_t*`. I am not sure if SWIG allows this -- but maybe it does. Try using a helper function:

```
tracks_t* empty_tracks() { return NULL; }
```

Alternatively, you can modify the "in" typemap along the following lines, attempting to convert the provided argument to a `track_t*` and passing its address, or alternatively passing the address of a `NULL` `track_t*`.

```
%typemap(in) track_t **phash_tracks (track_t *tracks) {
  // Alternatively, check if $input is a 0 integer `PyObject`...
  if ((SWIG_ConvertPtr($input, (void **) &tracks, $*1_descriptor, SWIG_POINTER_DISOWN)) == -1)
    tracks = NULL;
  $1 = &tracks;
}
```

Then, from Python, just pass something else to create `tracks`:

```
>>> int_res, tracks = g3.update_tracks(0, pdw_frame, rdw_frame, lib, lib_meta, cfg)
```

Comment: thanks for this, i have updated the OP with some additional detail

Comment: should there be an '&' somewhere in the 'in' typemap if we are trying to convert the track_t* tracks arg to track_t**? i.e. we are trying to get the address of tracks..

Comment: Yes, maybe the temporary `track_t* tracks` is required. I added it, and updated my answer with more explanations. Also, you can have a look at the generated wrapper code to see what exactly is happening (if you understand what typemaps basically do, you will be able to read the code).

Comment: your right - 1st time update_tracks() is called there is no track hash table, just the null pointer, so this is when the hash table is created, every subsequent call to update_tracks() just updates the existing track hash table. I've just been looking at the SWIG generated .py and .c code - will update my .i file with your update, rebuild and take another look..

Comment: I think that the helper function 'return NULL' is equivalent to tracks = None in python (see another of my questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726689/swig-python-initialise-a-pointer-to-null) you can see I've been trying to solve this problem for a long time!

Comment: for the typemap in (3) and (4) I get the error: TypeError: "'int' object is not iterable" when executing the python call to update_tracks()

Comment: You need the "argout" typemap in all cases, in addition to an "in" typemap. Are you using it that way? Otherwise the function just returns an `int`, which is not iterable.

Comment: you sir are a genius - I think it is working, it has been 2 and a bit years but worth the wait! I also wrote another type of helper fn, track_t *update_tracks_swig(track_t *hash_tracks, ...) but I think this might be haemorrhaging memory

Comment: Getting the memory management right is also an issue, but hard to do from afar, since it really depends on how you use the functions and where the memory gets allocated and deallocated. Probably, you never want Python to own a `tracks_t*` that represents a hash table, so better replace `SWIG_POINTER_OWN` with `0` in the argout typemap. For your helper function, if you do want Python to take ownership, use the `%newobject` directive. Also, you can check and set ownership from Python with `.thisown`, `.own()` and `.disown()`. Glad if these hints help get it working for you :-)